A CMake lib include & use other third party lib as git submodule, when use main lib in other project, error report that third party lib are missing
I have a CMake library project, which uses freetype as a git submodule. I have successfully built and installed my project. But when I use it via find_package(dearimgui) in another project, I got the error:
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:36 (find_package):
  Found package configuration file:

    ~/Dev/Project/project_name/cmake-build-debug/external/installed/lib/cmake/dearimgui/dearimgui-config.cmake

  but it set dearimgui_FOUND to FALSE so package "dearimgui" is considered to
  be NOT FOUND.  Reason given by package:

  The following imported targets are referenced, but are missing: freetype

I have found similar question here, but I could not get it right in my mind.
Here is my folder structure.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── imgui (git submodule, no CmakeLists.txt)
│   ├── source file
│ 
└── freetype (git submodule)
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── other.cc
    └── other.hh

Below is the content of my top-level CMakeLists.txt, which builds imgui (original imgui project doesn't have CMakeLists.txt):
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

project(dearimgui LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC)

add_subdirectory(freetype)

target_sources(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    PRIVATE
        imgui/imgui.cpp
        imgui/imgui_demo.cpp
        imgui/imgui_draw.cpp
        imgui/imgui_widgets.cpp
        imgui/imgui_tables.cpp
        imgui/misc/cpp/imgui_stdlib.cpp
        imgui/misc/freetype/imgui_freetype.cpp
        ${SOURCES}
)

include(GNUInstallDirs)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE freetype)

target_include_directories(
    ${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/imgui>
                           $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}>)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${SOURCE_DIR})
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

target_compile_definitions(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC
        IMGUI_DISABLE_INCLUDE_IMCONFIG_H
        IMGUI_INCLUDE_IMGUI_USER_H
        IMGUI_INCLUDE_IMGUI_USER_INL
        BX_CONFIG_DEBUG=0
        $<$<BOOL:${IMGUI_DISABLE_OBSOLETE_FUNCTIONS}>:IMGUI_DISABLE_OBSOLETE_FUNCTIONS>
)
target_compile_features(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE cxx_std_11)

set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
        DEBUG_POSTFIX "d"
)

install(
    TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
    EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}-config
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})
install(
    EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}-config
    NAMESPACE ${PROJECT_NAME}::
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/${PROJECT_NAME})

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}::freetype ALIAS freetype)

install(FILES
        imgui/imgui.h
        imgui/imconfig.h
        imgui/misc/cpp/imgui_stdlib.h
        imgui/imgui_internal.h
        imgui/imstb_textedit.h
        imgui/misc/freetype/imgui_freetype.h
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/dearimgui)

install(DIRECTORY ${SOURCE_DIR}
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/dearimgui
        FILES_MATCHING
        PATTERN "*.h"
        PATTERN "*.inl"
)

Below is content of freetype/CMakeLists.txt, which I have take from the freetype project (as git submodule):
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0...3.5)

if (NOT CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS 3.3)
  # Allow symbol visibility settings also on static libraries. CMake < 3.3
  # only sets the property on a shared library build.
  cmake_policy(SET CMP0063 NEW)

  # Support new IN_LIST if() operator.
  cmake_policy(SET CMP0057 NEW)
endif ()

include(CheckIncludeFile)
include(CMakeDependentOption)

# CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE must be set before `project' is called, which
# configures the base build environment and references the toolchain file
if (APPLE)
  if (DEFINED IOS_PLATFORM)
    if (NOT "${IOS_PLATFORM}" STREQUAL "OS"
        AND NOT "${IOS_PLATFORM}" STREQUAL "SIMULATOR"
        AND NOT "${IOS_PLATFORM}" STREQUAL "SIMULATOR64")
      message(FATAL_ERROR
        "IOS_PLATFORM must be set to either OS, SIMULATOR, or SIMULATOR64")
    endif ()
    if (NOT "${CMAKE_GENERATOR}" STREQUAL "Xcode")
      message(AUTHOR_WARNING
        "You should use Xcode generator with IOS_PLATFORM enabled to get Universal builds.")
    endif ()
    if (BUILD_SHARED_LIBS)
      message(FATAL_ERROR
        "BUILD_SHARED_LIBS can not be on with IOS_PLATFORM enabled")
    endif ()
    if (BUILD_FRAMEWORK)
      message(FATAL_ERROR
        "BUILD_FRAMEWORK can not be on with IOS_PLATFORM enabled")
    endif ()

    # iOS only uses static libraries
    set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS OFF)

    set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE
      ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/builds/cmake/iOS.cmake)
  endif ()
else ()
  if (DEFINED IOS_PLATFORM)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "IOS_PLATFORM is not supported on this platform")
  endif ()
endif ()


project(freetype C)

set(VERSION_MAJOR "2")
set(VERSION_MINOR "13")
set(VERSION_PATCH "2")

# Generate LIBRARY_VERSION and LIBRARY_SOVERSION.
set(LIBTOOL_REGEX "version_info='([0-9]+):([0-9]+):([0-9]+)'")
file(STRINGS "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/builds/unix/configure.raw"
  VERSION_INFO
  REGEX ${LIBTOOL_REGEX})
string(REGEX REPLACE
  ${LIBTOOL_REGEX} "\\1"
  LIBTOOL_CURRENT "${VERSION_INFO}")
string(REGEX REPLACE
  ${LIBTOOL_REGEX} "\\2"
  LIBTOOL_REVISION "${VERSION_INFO}")
string(REGEX REPLACE
  ${LIBTOOL_REGEX} "\\3"
  LIBTOOL_AGE "${VERSION_INFO}")

# This is what libtool does internally on Unix platforms.
math(EXPR LIBRARY_SOVERSION "${LIBTOOL_CURRENT} - ${LIBTOOL_AGE}")
set(LIBRARY_VERSION "${LIBRARY_SOVERSION}.${LIBTOOL_AGE}.${LIBTOOL_REVISION}")

# External dependency library detection is automatic.  See the notes at the
# top of this file, for how to force or disable dependencies completely.
option(FT_DISABLE_ZLIB
  "Disable use of system zlib and use internal zlib library instead." OFF)
cmake_dependent_option(FT_REQUIRE_ZLIB
  "Require system zlib instead of internal zlib library." OFF
  "NOT FT_DISABLE_ZLIB" OFF)

option(FT_DISABLE_BZIP2
  "Disable support of bzip2 compressed fonts." OFF)
cmake_dependent_option(FT_REQUIRE_BZIP2
  "Require support of bzip2 compressed fonts." OFF
  "NOT FT_DISABLE_BZIP2" OFF)

option(FT_DISABLE_PNG
  "Disable support of PNG compressed OpenType embedded bitmaps." OFF)
cmake_dependent_option(FT_REQUIRE_PNG
  "Require support of PNG compressed OpenType embedded bitmaps." OFF
  "NOT FT_DISABLE_PNG" OFF)

option(FT_DISABLE_HARFBUZZ
  "Disable HarfBuzz (used for improving auto-hinting of OpenType fonts)." OFF)
cmake_dependent_option(FT_REQUIRE_HARFBUZZ
  "Require HarfBuzz for improving auto-hinting of OpenType fonts." OFF
  "NOT FT_DISABLE_HARFBUZZ" OFF)

option(FT_DISABLE_BROTLI
  "Disable support of compressed WOFF2 fonts." OFF)
cmake_dependent_option(FT_REQUIRE_BROTLI
  "Require support of compressed WOFF2 fonts." OFF
  "NOT FT_DISABLE_BROTLI" OFF)

option(FT_ENABLE_ERROR_STRINGS
  "Enable support for meaningful error descriptions." OFF)

# Disallow in-source builds
if ("${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}" STREQUAL "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}")
  message(FATAL_ERROR
    "In-source builds are not permitted!  Make a separate folder for"
    " building, e.g.,\n"
    "  cmake -E make_directory build\n"
    "  cmake -E chdir build cmake ..\n"
    "Before that, remove the files created by this failed run with\n"
    "  cmake -E remove CMakeCache.txt\n"
    "  cmake -E remove_directory CMakeFiles")
endif ()


# Add local cmake modules
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/builds/cmake)


if (BUILD_FRAMEWORK)
  if (NOT "${CMAKE_GENERATOR}" STREQUAL "Xcode")
    message(FATAL_ERROR
      "You should use Xcode generator with BUILD_FRAMEWORK enabled")
  endif ()
  set(CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES "$(ARCHS_STANDARD)")
  set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS ON)
endif ()


# Find dependencies
include(FindPkgConfig)

if (NOT FT_DISABLE_HARFBUZZ)
  set(HARFBUZZ_MIN_VERSION "2.0.0")
  if (FT_REQUIRE_HARFBUZZ)
    find_package(HarfBuzz ${HARFBUZZ_MIN_VERSION} REQUIRED)
  else ()
    find_package(HarfBuzz ${HARFBUZZ_MIN_VERSION})
  endif ()
endif ()

if (NOT FT_DISABLE_PNG)
  if (FT_REQUIRE_PNG)
    find_package(PNG REQUIRED)
  else ()
    find_package(PNG)
  endif ()
  # FreePNG calls FindZLIB so unset ZLIB_FOUND to respect FT_DISABLE_ZLIB
  unset(ZLIB_FOUND)
endif ()

if (NOT FT_DISABLE_ZLIB)
  if (FT_REQUIRE_ZLIB)
    find_package(ZLIB REQUIRED)
  else ()
    find_package(ZLIB)
  endif ()
endif ()

if (NOT FT_DISABLE_BZIP2)
  # Genuine BZip2 does not provide bzip2.pc, but some platforms have it.
  # For better dependency in freetype2.pc, bzip2.pc is searched
  # regardless of the availability of libbz2. If bzip2.pc is found,
  # Requires.private is used instead of Libs.private.
  if (FT_REQUIRE_BZIP2)
    find_package(BZip2 REQUIRED)
  else ()
    find_package(BZip2)
  endif ()
  pkg_check_modules(PC_BZIP2 bzip2)
endif ()

if (NOT FT_DISABLE_BROTLI)
  if (FT_REQUIRE_BROTLI)
    find_package(BrotliDec REQUIRED)
  else ()
    find_package(BrotliDec)
  endif ()
endif ()

# Create the configuration file
if (UNIX AND NOT WIN32)
  check_include_file("unistd.h" HAVE_UNISTD_H)
  check_include_file("fcntl.h" HAVE_FCNTL_H)

  file(READ "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/builds/unix/ftconfig.h.in"
    FTCONFIG_H)
  if (HAVE_UNISTD_H)
    string(REGEX REPLACE
      "#undef +(HAVE_UNISTD_H)" "#define \\1 1"
      FTCONFIG_H "${FTCONFIG_H}")
  endif ()
  if (HAVE_FCNTL_H)
    string(REGEX REPLACE
      "#undef +(HAVE_FCNTL_H)" "#define \\1 1"
      FTCONFIG_H "${FTCONFIG_H}")
  endif ()
else ()
  file(READ "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/freetype/config/ftconfig.h"
    FTCONFIG_H)
endif ()

set(FTCONFIG_H_NAME "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/include/freetype/config/ftconfig.h")
if (EXISTS "${FTCONFIG_H_NAME}")
  file(READ "${FTCONFIG_H_NAME}" ORIGINAL_FTCONFIG_H)
else ()
  set(ORIGINAL_FTCONFIG_H "")
endif ()
if (NOT (ORIGINAL_FTCONFIG_H STREQUAL FTCONFIG_H))
  file(WRITE "${FTCONFIG_H_NAME}" "${FTCONFIG_H}")
endif ()


# Create the options file
file(READ "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/freetype/config/ftoption.h"
  FTOPTION_H)
if (ZLIB_FOUND)
  string(REGEX REPLACE
    "/\\* +(#define +FT_CONFIG_OPTION_SYSTEM_ZLIB) +\\*/" "\\1"
    FTOPTION_H "${FTOPTION_H}")
endif ()
if (BZIP2_FOUND)
  string(REGEX REPLACE
    "/\\* +(#define +FT_CONFIG_OPTION_USE_BZIP2) +\\*/" "\\1"
    FTOPTION_H "${FTOPTION_H}")
endif ()
if (PNG_FOUND)
  string(REGEX REPLACE
    "/\\* +(#define +FT_CONFIG_OPTION_USE_PNG) +\\*/" "\\1"
    FTOPTION_H "${FTOPTION_H}")
endif ()
if (HARFBUZZ_FOUND)
  string(REGEX REPLACE
    "/\\* +(#define +FT_CONFIG_OPTION_USE_HARFBUZZ) +\\*/" "\\1"
    FTOPTION_H "${FTOPTION_H}")
endif ()
if (BROTLIDEC_FOUND)
  string(REGEX REPLACE
    "/\\* +(#define +FT_CONFIG_OPTION_USE_BROTLI) +\\*/" "\\1"
    FTOPTION_H "${FTOPTION_H}")
endif ()

if (FT_ENABLE_ERROR_STRINGS)
  string(REGEX REPLACE
    "/\\* +(#define +FT_CONFIG_OPTION_ERROR_STRINGS) +\\*/" "\\1"
    FTOPTION_H "${FTOPTION_H}")
endif ()

set(FTOPTION_H_NAME "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/include/freetype/config/ftoption.h")
if (EXISTS "${FTOPTION_H_NAME}")
  file(READ "${FTOPTION_H_NAME}" ORIGINAL_FTOPTION_H)
else ()
  set(ORIGINAL_FTOPTION_H "")
endif ()
if (NOT (ORIGINAL_FTOPTION_H STREQUAL FTOPTION_H))
  file(WRITE "${FTOPTION_H_NAME}" "${FTOPTION_H}")
endif ()


file(GLOB PUBLIC_HEADERS "include/ft2build.h" "include/freetype/*.h")
file(GLOB PUBLIC_CONFIG_HEADERS "include/freetype/config/*.h")
file(GLOB PRIVATE_HEADERS "include/freetype/internal/*.h")


set(BASE_SRCS
  src/autofit/autofit.c
  src/base/ftbase.c
  src/base/ftbbox.c
  src/base/ftbdf.c
  src/base/ftbitmap.c
  src/base/ftcid.c
  src/base/ftfstype.c
  src/base/ftgasp.c
  src/base/ftglyph.c
  src/base/ftgxval.c
  src/base/ftinit.c
  src/base/ftmm.c
  src/base/ftotval.c
  src/base/ftpatent.c
  src/base/ftpfr.c
  src/base/ftstroke.c
  src/base/ftsynth.c
  src/base/fttype1.c
  src/base/ftwinfnt.c
  src/bdf/bdf.c
  src/bzip2/ftbzip2.c
  src/cache/ftcache.c
  src/cff/cff.c
  src/cid/type1cid.c
  src/gzip/ftgzip.c
  src/lzw/ftlzw.c
  src/pcf/pcf.c
  src/pfr/pfr.c
  src/psaux/psaux.c
  src/pshinter/pshinter.c
  src/psnames/psnames.c
  src/raster/raster.c
  src/sdf/sdf.c
  src/sfnt/sfnt.c
  src/smooth/smooth.c
  src/svg/svg.c
  src/truetype/truetype.c
  src/type1/type1.c
  src/type42/type42.c
  src/winfonts/winfnt.c
)

if (WIN32)
  list(APPEND BASE_SRCS "builds/windows/ftsystem.c")
elseif (UNIX)
  list(APPEND BASE_SRCS "builds/unix/ftsystem.c")
else ()
  list(APPEND BASE_SRCS "src/base/ftsystem.c")
endif ()

if (WIN32)
  enable_language(RC)
  list(APPEND BASE_SRCS builds/windows/ftdebug.c
                        src/base/ftver.rc)
elseif (WINCE)
  list(APPEND BASE_SRCS builds/wince/ftdebug.c)
else ()
  list(APPEND BASE_SRCS src/base/ftdebug.c)
endif ()

if (BUILD_FRAMEWORK)
  list(APPEND BASE_SRCS builds/mac/freetype-Info.plist)
endif ()


if (NOT DISABLE_FORCE_DEBUG_POSTFIX)
  set(CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX d)
endif ()


add_library(freetype
  ${PUBLIC_HEADERS}
  ${PUBLIC_CONFIG_HEADERS}
  ${PRIVATE_HEADERS}
  ${BASE_SRCS}
)

set_target_properties(
  freetype PROPERTIES
    C_VISIBILITY_PRESET hidden)

target_compile_definitions(
  freetype PRIVATE FT2_BUILD_LIBRARY)

if (WIN32)
  target_compile_definitions(
    freetype PRIVATE _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_WARNINGS)
  if (BUILD_SHARED_LIBS)
    target_compile_definitions(
      freetype PRIVATE DLL_EXPORT)
  endif ()
endif ()

if (BUILD_SHARED_LIBS)
  set_target_properties(freetype PROPERTIES
    VERSION ${LIBRARY_VERSION}
    SOVERSION ${LIBRARY_SOVERSION})
endif ()

# Pick up ftconfig.h and ftoption.h generated above, first.
target_include_directories(
  freetype
    PUBLIC
      $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include/freetype2>
      $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/include>
      $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
    PRIVATE
      ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/include
      ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include

      # Make <ftconfig.h> available for builds/unix/ftsystem.c.
      ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/include/freetype/config
)


if (BUILD_FRAMEWORK)
  set_property(SOURCE ${PUBLIC_CONFIG_HEADERS}
    PROPERTY MACOSX_PACKAGE_LOCATION Headers/config
  )
  set_target_properties(freetype PROPERTIES
    FRAMEWORK TRUE
    MACOSX_FRAMEWORK_INFO_PLIST ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/builds/mac/freetype-Info.plist
    PUBLIC_HEADER "${PUBLIC_HEADERS}"
    XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_INSTALL_PATH "@rpath"
  )
endif ()

# 'freetype-interface' is an interface library, to be accessed with
# `EXPORT_NAME Freetype::Freetype`.  This is the target name provided by
# CMake's `FindFreetype.cmake`, so we provide it for compatibility.
add_library(freetype-interface INTERFACE)
set_target_properties(freetype-interface PROPERTIES
  EXPORT_NAME Freetype::Freetype
  INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES freetype)

set(PKGCONFIG_REQUIRES "")
set(PKGCONFIG_REQUIRES_PRIVATE "")
set(PKGCONFIG_LIBS "-L\${libdir} -lfreetype")
set(PKGCONFIG_LIBS_PRIVATE "")

if (ZLIB_FOUND)
  target_link_libraries(freetype PRIVATE ${ZLIB_LIBRARIES})
  target_include_directories(freetype PRIVATE ${ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  list(APPEND PKGCONFIG_REQUIRES_PRIVATE "zlib")
endif ()
if (BZIP2_FOUND)
  target_link_libraries(freetype PRIVATE ${BZIP2_LIBRARIES})
  target_include_directories(freetype PRIVATE ${BZIP2_INCLUDE_DIR}) # not BZIP2_INCLUDE_DIRS
  if (PC_BZIP2_FOUND)
    list(APPEND PKGCONFIG_REQUIRES_PRIVATE "bzip2")
  else ()
    list(APPEND PKGCONFIG_LIBS_PRIVATE "-lbz2")
  endif ()
endif ()
if (PNG_FOUND)
  target_link_libraries(freetype PRIVATE ${PNG_LIBRARIES})
  target_compile_definitions(freetype PRIVATE ${PNG_DEFINITIONS})
  target_include_directories(freetype PRIVATE ${PNG_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  list(APPEND PKGCONFIG_REQUIRES_PRIVATE "libpng")
endif ()
if (HarfBuzz_FOUND)
  target_link_libraries(freetype PRIVATE ${HarfBuzz_LIBRARY})
  target_include_directories(freetype PRIVATE ${HarfBuzz_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  list(APPEND PKGCONFIG_REQUIRES_PRIVATE "harfbuzz >= ${HARFBUZZ_MIN_VERSION}")
endif ()
if (BROTLIDEC_FOUND)
  target_link_libraries(freetype PRIVATE ${BROTLIDEC_LIBRARIES})
  target_compile_definitions(freetype PRIVATE ${BROTLIDEC_DEFINITIONS})
  target_include_directories(freetype PRIVATE ${BROTLIDEC_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  list(APPEND PKGCONFIG_REQUIRES_PRIVATE "libbrotlidec")
endif ()


# Installation
include(GNUInstallDirs)

if (NOT SKIP_INSTALL_HEADERS AND NOT SKIP_INSTALL_ALL)
  install(
    # Note the trailing slash in the argument to `DIRECTORY'!
    DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/
      DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/freetype2
      COMPONENT headers
      PATTERN "internal" EXCLUDE
      PATTERN "ftconfig.h" EXCLUDE
      PATTERN "ftoption.h" EXCLUDE)
  install(
    FILES ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/include/freetype/config/ftconfig.h
          ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/include/freetype/config/ftoption.h
      DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/freetype2/freetype/config
      COMPONENT headers)
endif ()

if (NOT SKIP_INSTALL_LIBRARIES AND NOT SKIP_INSTALL_ALL)
  # Generate the pkg-config file
  file(READ "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/builds/unix/freetype2.in" FREETYPE2_PC_IN)

  string(REPLACE ";" ", " PKGCONFIG_REQUIRES_PRIVATE "${PKGCONFIG_REQUIRES_PRIVATE}")

  string(REPLACE "%prefix%" ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}
          FREETYPE2_PC_IN ${FREETYPE2_PC_IN})
  string(REPLACE "%exec_prefix%" "\${prefix}"
          FREETYPE2_PC_IN ${FREETYPE2_PC_IN})
  string(REPLACE "%libdir%" "\${prefix}/${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}"
          FREETYPE2_PC_IN ${FREETYPE2_PC_IN})
  string(REPLACE "%includedir%" "\${prefix}/${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}"
          FREETYPE2_PC_IN ${FREETYPE2_PC_IN})
  string(REPLACE "%ft_version%" "${LIBTOOL_CURRENT}.${LIBTOOL_REVISION}.${LIBTOOL_AGE}"
          FREETYPE2_PC_IN ${FREETYPE2_PC_IN})

  if (BUILD_SHARED_LIBS)
    string(REPLACE "%PKGCONFIG_REQUIRES%" "${PKGCONFIG_REQUIRES}"
            FREETYPE2_PC_IN ${FREETYPE2_PC_IN})
    string(REPLACE "%PKGCONFIG_REQUIRES_PRIVATE%" "${PKGCONFIG_REQUIRES_PRIVATE}"
            FREETYPE2_PC_IN ${FREETYPE2_PC_IN})
    string(REPLACE "%PKGCONFIG_LIBS%" "${PKGCONFIG_LIBS}"
            FREETYPE2_PC_IN ${FREETYPE2_PC_IN})
    string(REPLACE "%PKGCONFIG_LIBS_PRIVATE%" "${PKGCONFIG_LIBS_PRIVATE}"
            FREETYPE2_PC_IN ${FREETYPE2_PC_IN})
  else ()
    string(REPLACE "%PKGCONFIG_REQUIRES%" "${PKGCONFIG_REQUIRES} ${PKGCONFIG_REQUIRES_PRIVATE}"
            FREETYPE2_PC_IN ${FREETYPE2_PC_IN})
    string(REPLACE "%PKGCONFIG_REQUIRES_PRIVATE%" ""
            FREETYPE2_PC_IN ${FREETYPE2_PC_IN})
    string(REPLACE "%PKGCONFIG_LIBS%" "${PKGCONFIG_LIBS} ${PKGCONFIG_LIBS_PRIVATE}"
            FREETYPE2_PC_IN ${FREETYPE2_PC_IN})
    string(REPLACE "%PKGCONFIG_LIBS_PRIVATE%" ""
            FREETYPE2_PC_IN ${FREETYPE2_PC_IN})
  endif ()

  set(FREETYPE2_PC_IN_NAME "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/freetype2.pc")
  if (EXISTS "${FREETYPE2_PC_IN_NAME}")
    file(READ "${FREETYPE2_PC_IN_NAME}" ORIGINAL_FREETYPE2_PC_IN)
  else ()
    set(ORIGINAL_FREETYPE2_PC_IN "")
  endif ()
  if (NOT (ORIGINAL_FREETYPE2_PC_IN STREQUAL FREETYPE2_PC_IN))
    file(WRITE "${FREETYPE2_PC_IN_NAME}" ${FREETYPE2_PC_IN})
  endif ()

  install(
    FILES ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/freetype2.pc
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/pkgconfig
    COMPONENT pkgconfig)

  include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)
  write_basic_package_version_file(
    ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/freetype-config-version.cmake
    VERSION ${VERSION_MAJOR}.${VERSION_MINOR}.${VERSION_PATCH}
    COMPATIBILITY SameMajorVersion)

  install(
    TARGETS freetype freetype-interface
      EXPORT freetype-targets
      LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
      ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
      RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
      FRAMEWORK DESTINATION Library/Frameworks
      COMPONENT libraries)
  install(
    EXPORT freetype-targets
      DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/freetype
      FILE freetype-config.cmake
      COMPONENT headers)
  install(
    FILES ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/freetype-config-version.cmake
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/freetype
    COMPONENT headers)
endif ()


# Packaging
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_SUMMARY "The FreeType font rendering library.")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/README")
set(CPACK_RESOURCE_FILE_LICENSE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/LICENSE.TXT")

set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR ${VERSION_MAJOR})
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR ${VERSION_MINOR})
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_PATCH ${VERSION_PATCH})
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION "${CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR}.${CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR}.${CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_PATCH}")

if (WIN32)
  set(CPACK_GENERATOR ZIP)
else ()
  set(CPACK_GENERATOR TGZ)
endif ()

set(CPACK_COMPONENT_LIBRARIES_DISPLAY_NAME "Libraries")
set(CPACK_COMPONENT_HEADERS_DISPLAY_NAME "C/C++ Headers")
set(CPACK_COMPONENT_LIBRARIES_DESCRIPTION
  "Library used to build programs which use FreeType")
set(CPACK_COMPONENT_HEADERS_DESCRIPTION
  "C/C++ header files for use with FreeType")
set(CPACK_COMPONENT_HEADERS_DEPENDS libraries)
set(CPACK_COMPONENT_LIBRARIES_GROUP "Development")
set(CPACK_COMPONENT_HEADERS_GROUP "Development")

include(CPack)

Is there a way to fix this issue?
I have tried to incorporate freetype to the top-level CMakeLists.txt, and it works. But I want to use already existed freetype project.

Please, add to the question post the complete error message, like you see in the referenced question

@Tsyvarev thank you for the notice, I have edited my question.

When call find_package(dearimgui), it finds and executes script dearimgui-config.cmake, which is created via install(EXPORT) command of your project. The export set dearimgui-config, from which given command creates the script, contains definition only of the target dearimgui (according to calls of install(TARGETS ... EXPORT) with given export set).
In your project, the target dearimgui is linked (via target_link_libraries) with freetype target, so that linkage is transmitted into script dearimgui-config.cmake too. But given script doesn't know the target freetype, and this is what the error message tells you.
You need to create dearimgui-config.cmake script which is aware of freetype target.
The target freetype comes from the subproject, and that subproject installs the target and exports its (install(TARGETS ... EXPORT freetype-targets ...)). Given export set is installed as script freetype-config.cmake, which, as you could guess, will be used by find_package(freetype).
Like in the referenced question you need to rename the file you create from the export set dearimgui-config:
install(
    EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}-config
    NAMESPACE ${PROJECT_NAME}::
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/${PROJECT_NAME}
    # Rename installed file to be not confused with the script executed by 
    # find_package(dearimgui)
    FILE dearimguiTargets.cmake)

and instead create true script dearimgui-config.cmake which is aware of all targets:
include(CMakeFindDependencyMacro)
# This will provide 'freetype' target.
find_dependency(freetype)
# .. for use that target in the following script.
include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/dearimguiTargets.cmake")

(That true script should be installed via install(FILES) command into the same directory, as you install the file dearimguiTargets.cmake).

this solved my issue, thank for explain this to me
